# TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined with Image-Slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error, next.js, strapi

I'm currently working on a website where I use **Strapi** as a CMS and **Next.js(React)** in Frontend. The site also has an image slider which obviousely contains an image, a headline and a description.

After some time on the website the following error occurs and the slider stops from working or does things like showing all slides really fast one behind the other. What can I do to solve this?

*Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Canot read property 'classList' of undefined*

I've already tried many solutions I found here on StackOverflow, but nothing worked... I am just not able to find the error in my code, which is the following: (/components/image-slider file)

```
    import ...
const Slider = ({...}) => {

 if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-navig');
    let currentSlide = 1;
    
    // Javascript for image slider manual navigation
    var manualNav = function(manual){
        slides.forEach((slide) => {
        slide.classList.remove('active');
    
        btns.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.classList.remove('active');
        });
        });
    
        slides[manual].classList.add('active');
        btns[manual].classList.add('active');
    }
    
        btns.forEach((btn, i) => {
        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            manualNav(i);
            currentSlide = i;
        });
        });
    
        // // Javascript for image slider autoplay navigation
        var repeat = function(activeClass){
        let active = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
        let i = 1;
    
        var repeater = () => {
            setTimeout(function(){
            [...active].forEach((activeSlide) => {
                activeSlide.classList.remove('active');
            });
    
            slides[i].classList.add('active');
            btns[i].classList.add('active');
            i++;
    
            if(slides.length == i){
            i = 0;
            }
            if(i >= slides.length){
            return;
            }
            repeater();
        }, 10000);
        }
        repeater();
        }
        repeat();
    }

    if (error) {
        return <div>An error occured: {error.message}</div>;
    }
    return (
        <div className="img-slider">
            <div className="slide active">
                <div className="info">
                   // content 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="slide">
                <div className="info">
                // content 
                </div>
            </div>
            // further slides
        
            <div className="navigation">
                <div className="btn-navig active"></div>
                <div className="btn-navig"></div>
                <div className="btn-navig"></div>
            </div>
        
        </div>
    );
    };

// axios request ...

export default Slider;
```

I hope someone can help me with the above mentioned problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to move all the if block to useEffect because the first time this code run slides and btn, etc are null/undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first flaw in the code is this one

```
var manualNav = function(manual){
    slides.forEach((slide) => {
    slide.classList.remove('active');

    btns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove('active');
    });
    });

    slides[manual].classList.add('active');
    btns[manual].classList.add('active');
}
```

Here, with every new `slide` of `slides[]`, you start a new `btns[]` loop.

```
    btns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove('active');
    });
```

But this is just unnecessary processing time that gets lost. Do it this way:

```
var manualNav = function(manual){
    slides.forEach((slide) => {
        slide.classList.remove('active');
    });

    btns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove('active');
    });
    
    slides[manual].classList.add('active');
    btns[manual].classList.add('active');
}
```

Your actual problem is this.

You have 3 `div` with the class `btn-navig` but only 2 with the class `slide`. But in your `repeater()` you increase `i` by 1 with every new loop.

```
 slides[i].classList.add('active');
 btns[i].classList.add('active');
 i++;
```

With the second iteration you have the following situation:

```
 slides[2].classList.add('active');  // undefined
 btns[2].classList.add('active'); // value
```

There is no `slides[2]` as only `slides[0]` and `slides[1]` have values.

You have to rethink your indexing-approach.

Comment: Ok, wow - thanks a lot for your help! I think it could work when adding the following code after the if statements:               if(i >= slides.lenght > 2) {
                    window.clearInterval();
                    return;
                }